# Grep pattern from file

Tags: files, grep

I have two files.

File1

```
Als  
Mmp  
Ggt1
```

File2 (separated by tabs)

```
cy3 cy5 ID GeneName Zscore  
18 18 NM23XX Als 2.34886  
456 487 NM375FG Rac 0.898549
```

I want to `grep` the list of file1 in file2. I want the return to be something like:

```
18 18 NM23XX Als 2.34886
```

I used

```
grep -f file1 file2
```

but the return is the entire file with the matches highlighted in red. I want only the matching lines. I also tried

```
grep -x -f file1 file2
```

And there was no return. What can I do?

Comment: What does "the list of a file in another file" mean? Normally grep looks for patterns that are specified on the command line. Are you trying to compare files to see what the differences are?

Comment: Add the `-o` option to get only the matches!

Comment: I have a list of genes in a file and I want to see if they appear in another file.

Comment: What is the format of the list of genes? Probably it looks like the whole file is being returned because the lines are very long?

Comment: I want the entire line where the match appears. If I use -o I only get the match.

Comment: Please give a test case example!

Comment: It is only one column with the list; it's not even a long list, ~30 gene names.

Comment: edit your question and add a sample so we know what we are doing.

Comment: Looking at the grep man page, it looks like the first command should do what you want. (`grep -f file1 file2`). There's probably something going on with your particular files.

Comment: ... Windows style line-endings for example (so that the patterns look like `Als\r`)

Comment: Even an extra newline at the end of file1 will cause the whole file to be output.  Clean that up and the suggest grep -f file1 file2 should work as you desire.

Answer (score 0):

```
for gene in $(cat file1); do cat file2 | grep $gene; done
18      18      NM23XX  Als     2.34886
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be doing the correct thing:

```
$ cat f1
Als
Mmp
Ggt1

$ cat f2
cy3 cy5 ID GeneName Zscore  
18 18 NM23XX Als 2.34886  
456 487 NM375FG Rac 0.898549 

$ grep  -f f1  f2
18 18 NM23XX Als 2.34886  

$ grep --version
grep (GNU grep) 3.1
...
```

Perhaps your f1 file has trailing whitespace on the "Als" line?